# To build a for loop, how can I use variable names in count() command?

Tags: r, loops, count

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plyr) 

df <- data.frame(x = sample(c("Large", "Medium", "Small"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
                 y = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
                 z = sample(c("High", "Low"), 10, replace = TRUE))
    
df %>% 
  count('x') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,freq)) +  
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") -> a
    
df %>% 
  count('y') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y,freq)) +  
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") -> b
    
df %>% 
  count('z') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(z,freq)) +  
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") -> c
    
grid.arrange(a, b, c, ncol = 3, nrow = 1)
```

Instead of writing the above code twice, I want to build a loop like given below:

```r
for (val in names(df)) {
  df %>% 
    count(get(val)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(get(val),freq)) +  
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
}
```

I am receiving an error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'x' not found".

Comment: `%>%` is in package `dplyr`
`count()` function is in `plyr`

I have also included this in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the `count`, as you can just use `geom_bar()` without the `stat` call to plot it correctly.  Just make this into a function (taking care to use `aes_` since you're using it programmatically) and use `lapply`.

```
plot_stuff <- function(x, val) {

  x %>%
    ggplot(aes_(x = as.name(val))) +
    geom_bar()

}

plots <- lapply(names(df), plot_stuff, x = df)

grid.arrange(grobs = plots, ncol = 3, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can also use for loop to get the solution. The code is given below. However, solution provided by Jake is better.

````
df = data.frame(x = sample(c("Large","Medium", "Small"), 10, replace = TRUE), y = sample(c("Yes","No"), 10, replace = TRUE), z = sample(c("High","Low"), 10, replace = TRUE) )

i <- c(0)
for (val in names(df)){
 i <- i+1
 assign(paste("bar",i,sep="_"), ggplot(df, aes_(as.name(val))) + geom_bar())
}
grid.arrange(bar_1, bar_2, bar_3, ncol = 3, nrow = 1)
```
````